# How to order Django Queryset by a specified match and then default to the original ordering for all unmatched items?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

### Background:

I would like to know how I can implement some advanced ordering of Django Querysets based upon matching a requested item first, and then defaulting to the original ordering scheme for all unmatched items.

Lets say I have the following:

```
possibleLanguages = ["English", "Spanish", "Armenian", "French", "Chinese", "Swahili"]
requestedLanguage = "Armenian"

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    languages_available = models.CharField(max_length=1000) #Comma Separated List of languages

#Pseudocode Query
queryset = Book.objects.all().order_by(sortByRequestLanguage(requestedLanguage),
                                       sortByTotalNumLanguagesAvailable(),
                                       sortByAllPossibleLanguages()
                                      )
```

### Question:

How can I order the resulting Book queryset by:
 1. Sorting all objects on whether they match a specified Language 
 2. Sorting all sorted objects of (1) by total number of available languages
 3. Sorting all sorted objects of (2) by all other languages in possibleLanguages

Comment: I think you are confusing querying data and its processing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty complex sort. I'm going to take a stab at a solution. You definitely need to do some raw sql, so I am going to use PostGres for an example. First, you need to add a column in the query to do the sorting on. Then, just sort on that column. This is my example:

```
Book.object.extra(
    select={'sort': 'CASE WHEN name LIKE %s THEN 0 ELSE array_length(string_to_array(name, ','), 1) + 1 END',
    select_params=['%' + requestedLanguage + '%']
).order_by('sort')
```

A few things to note:

1. If the requestedLanguage is in the languages_available comma separated languages, that `Book` will be ordered first. (order 0)
2. Next, everything else will be sorted by the count of the languages_available.
3. As for the third sort you requested, I'm not sure what you want exactly. I'm confused because the field is actually a list of languages.
4. I think it might be easier to sort if the languages_available was a manytomany field to another table of languages.
5. Finally, I'm not sure if you can use `.order_by()` on a column that was created in `.extra()` you might need to use a `.raw()` query.

I'm not sure if this will work for you at all, but hopefully it will push you in the right direction.